# How do I make a switch to dark/light mode button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm looking to make a button that can change the theme of my app, this button would be located in the settings page. Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution yet, all I could find on the internet was ways to switch themes dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have single page its very easy just use Setstate to change the color but if you want to change multiple widgets/pages I suggest learning Provider-> ChangeNotifierProvider. Because every page needs to listen to the color that's currently selected and rebuild the widget if the color changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm still a beginner using flutter and your answer was very useful

Answer (score 4):

The answer above is correct.  Here is some code to help you visualize the solution.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
      // Used MultiProvider incase you have other providers
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeDataProvider>(
          create: (_) => ThemeDataProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeDataProvider themeDataProvider = Provider.of(context);

    // Pull the theme data from the provider and make a few modification
    // The modifications are for illustration only.  Not required.
    final ThemeData currentTheme = themeDataProvider.themeData.copyWith(
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: themeDataProvider.isDarkTheme ? Colors.yellow[700] : Colors.yellow[300],
      appBarTheme: themeDataProvider.themeData.appBarTheme,
      cardTheme: themeDataProvider.themeData.cardTheme,
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.yellow[100],
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: currentTheme, //set your theme
      initialRoute: setupRoute,
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}


class ThemeDataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _useDarkTheme;
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
  ThemeDataProvider() {
    _useDarkTheme = false;
    _loadPrefs();
  }

  ThemeData get themeData => _useDarkTheme ? myThemeDark : myThemeLight; //MyTheme... is defined by you

  bool get isDarkTheme => _useDarkTheme;

  void toggleTheme() {
    _useDarkTheme = !_useDarkTheme;
    _savePrefs();
    notifyListeners();
  }

//The reset is just incase you want to save the selected theme for the next time your app is run.
  _initPrefs() async {
    if (_prefs == null) {
      _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    }
  }

  _loadPrefs() async {
    await _initPrefs();
    _useDarkTheme = _prefs.getBool("useDarkMode") ?? true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  _savePrefs() async {
    await _initPrefs();
    await _prefs.setBool("useDarkMode", _useDarkTheme);
  }
}
```

It is really staight forward once you use it a few times.

Good luck!

Comment: I should have added that you can add a toggle button anywhere in you app and call toggleTheme on the provider.

Answer (score 1):

install get package [getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) and  then you can switch your moods like this :

```
Get.isDarkMode? Get.changeTheme(ThemeData.light()):Get.changeTheme(ThemeData.dark());
```